# Store 1000 values in singlecolumn of single table in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I am very new to MySQL. I want to store 1000 or more values into a table of single column. After saving 100 values I got this:

> mysql 139 storage engine error..

Comment: A little more information would be nice.  What does your query look like?

Comment: You need to post the SQL you are using to insert the values...

Comment: i want to enter 1000 values in txt file that stores into database in that i have to take first two max values.I a m able to enter only 100 after that error.but first two max values is 250 values and 350 value in txt file i have..

Comment: You still haven't posted the actual query or code you're using.

Comment: INSERT into Telerythm VALUES('"+"600"+"',"+now+",'"+sb1.toString()+"');

Comment: The values will come from a txt file and save to id(600) to current time.in txt file if i give more that 100 values while storing into table at that time it shows 139 error

Comment: Voting to close as unclear, since no [mcve] has been provided.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using the InnoDB or MyISAM engine? This error normally means that you exceeded the allowed row length. Please post your table structure here.

You can do that from a command line client by issuing the command:

```
SHOW CREATE TABLE yourtable;
```

Comment: Hopefully since asking this question the OP has decided that storing 1000 comma delimited values in a single column has certain drawbacks and abandoned the idea!